# How to set a http proxy in nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx from windows 8.
I want to set http proxy for my nginx reverse proxy.
**Is there any solution for this matter?**

Answer (score 0):

You can make nginx work as an http proxy editing your `nginx.conf` something like this:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     yourdomain.com;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234;
```

}
}

[also see the official documentation](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/)